# getting error when getting array data with where condition from MYSQL in android

Tags: android-studio

I want to get all data which is available with the specific username from the table in listview using adapter.

I got error "org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject".

below is code

PHP file is working perfectly. I get all data which is available with the specified username.

ExpenseList.php

```
<?php 

require_once("Config.php");

    $response = array();

    if(isset($_GET['apicall'])){

        switch($_GET['apicall']){

            case 'expense':
                if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('username'))){
                    $username = $_POST['username'];

                    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM Expense_Master WHERE VV_User_Name = '$username' ORDER BY VD_Expense_Date ASC");

                    $stmt->execute();

                    $stmt->store_result();

                    if($stmt->num_rows > 0){

                        $stmt->bind_result($expenseid, $userid, $username, $entrydate, $expensedate, $credit, $debit, $description, $modifieddate);

                        $products = array(); 
                         while($stmt->fetch()){
                             $temp = array();
                             $temp['expenseid'] = $expenseid; 
                             $temp['userid'] = $userid; 
                             $temp['username'] = $username; 
                             $temp['entrydate'] = $entrydate; 
                             $temp['expensedate'] = $expensedate; 
                             $temp['credit'] = $credit; 
                             $temp['debit'] = $debit; 
                             $temp['description'] = $description; 
                             $temp['modifieddate'] = $modifieddate; 
                             array_push($products, $temp);

                             $response['error'] = false; 
                             $response['message'] = 'Fetch successfull';
                        }

                    }else{
                        $response['error'] = false; 
                        $response['message'] = 'Invalid username';
                    }
                }
            break; 

                $response['error'] = true; 
                $response['message'] = 'Invalid Operation Called';
        }

    }else{
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = 'Invalid API Call';
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
    echo json_encode($products);

    function isTheseParametersAvailable($params){

        foreach($params as $param){
            if(!isset($_POST[$param])){
                return false; 
            }
        }
        return true; 
    }
?>
```

Here is ExpenseList.JAVA

```
private static final String EXPENSE_URL = "http:server.com/ExpenseList.php?apicall=expense";
private List<ExpenseListNotes> userNotes = new ArrayList<>();
ListView listView;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_expense_list);

        spinnerUserNotes = new ArrayList<SpinnerUserNotes>();
        expenseData();
    }

private void expenseData() {

        //if everything is fine

        class expenseData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);


                try {

                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(s);

                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                            //getting product object from json array
                            JSONObject product = array.getJSONObject(i);

                            userNotes.add(new ExpenseListNotes(
                                    product.getInt("expenseid"),
                                    product.getString("userid"),
                                    product.getString("username"),
                                    product.getString("entrydate"),
                                    product.getString("expensedate"),
                                    product.getString("credit"),
                                    product.getString("debit"),
                                    product.getString("description")));
                        }
                        ExpenseListAdapter adapter = new ExpenseListAdapter(ExpenseList.this, userNotes);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error : "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("Error", e.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                //creating request handler object
                RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

                //creating request parameters
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("username", "Alpesh");

                //returing the response
                return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(URL_EXPENSE, params);
            }
        }

        expenseData ul = new expenseData();
        ul.execute();
    }
```

Here is AdapterClass

```
private class ExpenseListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private Context context;
        private List<ExpenseListNotes> invoiceModelArrayList;

        public ExpenseListAdapter(Context context, List<ExpenseListNotes> invoiceModelArrayList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.invoiceModelArrayList = (List<ExpenseListNotes>) invoiceModelArrayList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return invoiceModelArrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return invoiceModelArrayList.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int i, View v, ViewGroup viewGroup)
        {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            ButterKnife.bind(this, v);

            if (v == null)
            {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_expense_list, null, true);

                holder.tvRELUserid = v.findViewById(R.id.tvRELUserid);
                holder.tvRELExpenseID = v.findViewById(R.id.tvRELExpenseID);
                holder.tvRELUsername = v.findViewById(R.id.tvRELUsername);
                holder.tvRELCredit = v.findViewById(R.id.tvRELCredit);
                holder.tvRELDebit = v.findViewById(R.id.tvRELDebit);
                holder.tvRELExpenseDate = v.findViewById(R.id.tvRELExpenseDate);
                holder.tvRELEntryDate = v.findViewById(R.id.tvRELEntryDate);
                holder.tvRELDescription = v.findViewById(R.id.tvRELDescription);
                holder.btnDelete = v.findViewById(R.id.btnRELDelete);
                holder.btnUpdate = v.findViewById(R.id.btnRELUpdate);
                v.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
            }

            holder.tvRELExpenseID.setText(String.valueOf(invoiceModelArrayList.get(i).getExpenseID()));
            holder.tvRELUserid.setText(String.valueOf(invoiceModelArrayList.get(i).getUserID()));
            holder.tvRELUsername.setText(String.valueOf(invoiceModelArrayList.get(i).getUsername()));
            holder.tvRELCredit.setText(String.valueOf(invoiceModelArrayList.get(i).getCredit()));
            holder.tvRELDebit.setText(String.valueOf(invoiceModelArrayList.get(i).getDebit()));
            holder.tvRELExpenseDate.setText(String.valueOf(invoiceModelArrayList.get(i).getExpenseDate()));
            holder.tvRELEntryDate.setText(String.valueOf(invoiceModelArrayList.get(i).getEntryDate()));
            holder.tvRELDescription.setText(String.valueOf(invoiceModelArrayList.get(i).getDescription()));
            return v;
        }

        public void setFilter(List<ExpenseListNotes> newList)
        {
            invoiceModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            invoiceModelArrayList.addAll(newList);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvRELUserid, tvRELExpenseID, tvRELUsername, tvRELCredit, tvRELDebit, tvRELExpenseDate, tvRELEntryDate, tvRELDescription;
        Button btnDelete, btnUpdate;
    }
```

Code for RequestHandler.Class

```
public class RequestHandler
{

    public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> postDataParams)
    {
        URL url;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            url = new URL(requestURL);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                String response;

                while ((response = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(response);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }


    //this method is converting keyvalue pairs data into a query string as needed to send to the server
    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet())
        {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: That error is because `[]` would be a JSONArray, not a JSONObject. The error should also be specifying which line of code is the issue, so you can check if that particular field is being assigned to the right data type.

Comment: Also, in `ExpenseList.java` you are creating a JSONObject from the response string, after which you are creating a **new** JSONArray rather then maybe retrieving the one present in the response at the "user" key. Is that intended?

Comment: Where can i check that?

Comment: sorry its my mistake i replace it.

Comment: @TheGamer007 i edited my code. i got message from php file sucessful but in android get Error : org.json.JSONException: Value {"error":false,"message":"Fetch successfull"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP, so I'm not sure what the response string is. But in your case it seems that the response string received is that Object with the keys `error` and `message`. That should be a `JSONObject`, like before. Which line had the previous original error mentioned in the question? Because apart from that error and message, you should also be sending the actual results of the query. You seem to be storing that in `$products`, but is it being posted?

Comment: PHP script works fine. I get all data which is specified username from PHP Script.. issue is in android coding.